# Loading OpenLayers Features without loading and displaying the whole surrounding map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

```
 var config = {
    geoserver: "http://url/geoserver/",
    wms_layer: "tt/wms?service=WMS",
    wfs_layer: "tt/wfs",
    featureNS: "url2",
    init_center : new OpenLayers.Bounds(363273.29099999997,5770864.300999998),
    init_zoom : 4,
    maxExtent:  new OpenLayers.Bounds(363052,5770362,363467,5771122)
}; 

map = new OpenLayers.Map({
  div:"map",
  //zoom:0,
  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection(epsg),
  units: "m",
  maxResolution: 2,
  maxExtent: config.maxExtent,
});

var layer_selectable = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
  strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(),saveStrategy],
  protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
  url: config.geoserver + config.wfs_layer,
  version: "1.1.0",
  featureType: "ftype",
  featureNS: config.featureNS,
  srsName: epsg
  }),
  renderers: renderer
}); 

function doSomething() {
   var myFeatures = layer_selectable.getFeaturesByAttribute("fid","<?= $fid ?>");
   alert(myFeatures);
}

 layer_selectable.events.register("loadend", layer_selectable,doSomething);
  map.addLayers([layer_selectable]);
  map.setCenter(config.init_center.getCenterLonLat(),config.init_zoom);
```

I am absolutely new to OpenLayers. I found this code. What I want now, is to retrieve the 'myFeatures' data from the webserver without having to load and display the whole Map and the layer. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: You mean to only show the WMS tiles that intersect with the WFS request?

Comment: as far as I understand the issue, yes.

Comment: erm, ok, unusual request. So what do you want to show instead of WMS tiles. White space?